# Error in using datamash in Bash script on txt file with multiple rows and columns

Tags: bash

I have a .txt file containing ~1 million rows and 11 columns. Only the first column has alphabetical values while the rest 2-11 columns have numeric values. An example given below:

[Image of the Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPy1S.jpg)

I used datamash to group column 1 by taking the mean of each value in col 2 to col 11 columnwise. So the result must look like this

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgfOo.jpg)

I tried this  code in bash script:

```
datamash --sort --whitespace --headers groupby 1 mean 2-11 < infilename.txt > outfilename.txt
```

It is giving me this error:

```
'atamash: invalid numeric value in line 2 field 11: '3.510344247
```

I have checked multiple times that there is no single quotation in my data at line 2 field 11..I even remove all the special characters and only kept the alphanumeric values and whitespace as delimiter, then again ran the same command and getting the same error. It is only targeting the column 11 becoz when I run the above command from 2-10 it is giving me the correct result.

What is it that i am doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to include sample input and expected outputs as text blocks rather than images.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the same error in the internet and got the solution that the error 'atamash: invalid numeric value in is becoz i have to convert the dos .txt file into unix file. So using dos2unix command i converted the file the file and run the above code. Its worked! So i am posting this comment for future consideration.

Comment: datamash developer here! Yeah, it assumes the input data has the correct line endings for the system being used.